# !\qsetw command compulsory in complex LF trees?

Tags: linguistics, qtree

I've been working with a Latex tutorial by a semanticist and I have been really struggling with the code for this LF representation (using `qtree`). I studied the example code for a complex tree super diligently and built my own code for a new LF representation. I am quite sure this should be the right code. Yet Latex does not want to compile.

The only thing I did not adopt from the tutorial file is the `!\qsetw{}` command which is supposed to manipulate the width of the tree.

But from what I understand from other tutorials on `qtree`, using this command is not compulsory, i.e. Latex is capable of computing the spacing of your tree as it is.

But then again I am not sure. Could it be that Latex needs me to use `!\qsetw{}` before it can compile?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi,BCOR=8mm,headsepline,headings=normal,openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{linguex} 
\usepackage[center]{qtree} 
\usepackage{tree-dvips} 
\makeatletter
\def\qroof#1.#2 {{%
    \setbox\@qrscratchbox = \hbox{\let\qtreepadding=\qroofpadding
            \qshow@text[l]{\qleafhook}{#1}}%
        \def\qtreepadding{0pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\setbox\@tempboxa = \hbox{\qshow@text{\qlabelhook}{#2}}%
\ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>0pt \box\@tempboxa \\ \fi
\unitlength=\wd\@qrscratchbox \qdraw@roof \\[-0.6ex]
\box\@qrscratchbox
\end{tabular}}}
\makeatother
\qroofy=1
\qroofx=2
\begin{document}
\ex.
\Tree 
[.$_{\langle v,t\rangle}$ {\textit {Floyd} \\ $_{\langle e \rangle}$} 
[. $_{\langle e, \langle v,t \rangle\rangle}$ 
[.$_{\langle \langle r,t \rangle, \langle e, \langle v,t \rangle \rangle}$ {\textit {AUG-SPEED} \\ $_{\langle \langle\langle e, \langle v,t \rangle \rangle, \langle \langle r,t \rangle \langle e, \langle v,t \rangle\rangle\rangle}$} 
\qroof{walk}.$_{\langle e, \langle v,t, \rangle\rangle}$
] 
\qroof{quickly}.$_{\langle r,t \rangle}$
]
]
\par 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community!
Could you post your code so we can see where the problem is?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to tell. But I would recommend you switch from `qtree` to either `tikz-qtree` or `forest`, then you won't need to mess around with manual tweaks like `!qsetw`. But the linguistic representation (LF or not) certainly has no bearing on whether your tree compiles.

Comment: The most common error you get with `qtree` and `tikz-qtree` is described here: [I'm getting the error: ! Paragraph ended before \@@label was complete](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/63008). Maybe this is the problem with your tree too.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. This runs without error for me. What exactly is the problem? And why have you redefined `\qroof`? If the problem is just that the tree spacing is bad, there's not much to be done with that, as `qtree` doesn't do much to compact the tree. In my answer I give you a couple of alternatives.

Comment: Now it runs without error for me too! The tree structure is a weird one but that's much easier to solve. I think I'll figure out the bracketing and then see how the spacing works out for me. In any case I think the alternatives you gave will be very helpful because the structures are quite complex and probably will require a compact tree representation. Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't be typing all your types manually. Use a macro. I'll add a cleaned up version of your tree to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version of your tree with various things cleaned up. First, typing all your semantic types manually make the source tree very hard to read, and also much more prone to errors. You're also abusing the subscript command to make the types a smaller font. So I've first defined a macro to introduce a type. (Thanks to David Carlisle and egreg for help in chat.)

```
\newcommand{\type}[1]{\ensuremath{\substack{\langle#1\rangle}}}
```

This allows you to use `\type{e,t}` to produce a correctly bracketed type. Note that <*e*>  is not a type (but *e* is), and should not be enclosed in angle brackets.

I've also removed the redefinition of `\qroof` which as far as I can tell doesn't do anything.

Now here's your tree with `qtree`. As you can see, no instances of `!\qsetw` are needed, although the spacing of the tree isn't very pretty.

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi,BCOR=8mm,headsepline,headings=normal,openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[center]{qtree} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \substack command
\newcommand{\type}[1]{\ensuremath{\substack{\langle#1\rangle}}}

\qroofy=1
\qroofx=2
\begin{document}

\Tree 
[.\type{v,t} 
    {\textit {Floyd}\\$e$} 
    [.\type{e,\type{v,t}} 
        [.\type{\type{r,t},\type{e,\type{v,t}}} 
            [.{\textit{AUG-SPEED} \\ \type{\type{e,\type{v,t}},\type{\type{r,t},\type{e,\type{v,t}}}}}  ]
\qroof{walk}.{\type{e,\type{v,t}}} 
] 
\qroof{quickly}.\type{r,t} ]
]


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Here's  a more general answer to the question. Because of the spacing issues with `qtree`  I suggest that switching to either `tikz-qtree` or `forest` might be a preferable solution for complex trees.

### `qtree`

The  `!\qsetw` command is never required in a `qtree` tree. It can be useful to manually tweak the width of a node, but since it's a manual intervention, it becomes tedious to use extensively.  Here's an example tree with `qtree`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt,varwidth=11in]{standalone}
\usepackage{qtree}
\begin{document}
Tree using \texttt{qtree} without using \verb|!\qsetw|:

\Tree 
[.S      \qroof{this is a big noun phrase}.NP 
        [.VP
        [.VP 
             \qroof{this is big noun phrase}.NP 
            [.V\1 
                [.V\\shows ]
                [.NP\\something ]
            ]
        ]
        \qroof{with an adverbial phrase}.PP
        ]
]
\end{document}
```

[image: qtree tree]

As you can see, `qtree` doesn't compact the tree very well by itself. So to make the tree more compact we would need to use `!\qsetw` commands to manually fix the widths. Here's an adjusted tree:

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt,varwidth=11in]{standalone}
\usepackage{qtree}
\begin{document}

Tree using \texttt{qtree} adjusted using \verb|!\qsetw|:

\Tree 
[.S      \qroof{this is a big noun phrase}.NP 
        [.VP !\qsetw{-3cm}
        [.VP 
             \qroof{this is big noun phrase}.NP 
            [.V\1 
                [.V\\shows ]
                [.NP\\something ]
            ]
        ]
        !\qsetw{4cm}
        \qroof{with an adverbial phrase}.PP
        ]
]
```

[image: adjusted tree]

### `tikz-qtree`

We can get a more compact tree automatically if we use the `tikz-qtree` package. This package uses exactly the same syntax for specifying trees as `qtree` but uses the powerful TikZ package for rendering the tree. You can see that this tree is vertically more compact than the `qtree` trees, but still not particularly compact horizontally.

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt,varwidth=11in]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\tikzset{every tree node={align=center,anchor=north}}
\begin{document}

Tree using \texttt{tikz-qtree}:

\Tree 
[.S     [.NP \edge[roof]; {this is a big noun phrase} ]
        [.VP
        [.VP 
            [.NP \edge [roof]; {this is big noun phrase} ]
            [.V\1 
                [.V\\shows ]
                [.NP\\something ]
            ]
        ]
        [.PP \edge[roof]; {with an adverbial phrase} ]
        ]
]
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz-qtree tree]

### `forest`

We can achieve the most compact tree by using the `forest` package. It also uses TikZ, and has a slightly different tree syntax: node labels do not need a `.` prefix (as they do in both `qtree` and `tikz-qtree`, but terminal nodes also need to be bracketed (which they don't in `qtree` and `tikz-qtree`).

You can see here that the tree is horizontally much more compact than the `qtree` or `tikz-qtree` trees, because `forest` aims to make the most compact tree it can.

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt,varwidth=11in]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\def\1{$'$}
\begin{document}

Tree using \texttt{forest}:

\begin{forest}
[S      [NP [{this is a big noun phrase}, roof] ] 
        [VP
        [VP 
            [NP [{this is a big noun phrase}, roof]  ]
            [V\1 
                [V\\shows ]
                [NP\\something ]
            ]
        ]
        [PP [{with an adverbial phrase},roof] ]
        ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: forest tree]

Comment: Thank you for the comment and the illustrations! It's very helpful. I went back to my comment and added the code as you asked. What I'm realizing now is that there is probably a coding rule in the source code I am adopting that I haven't gotten correctly. As far as I can see you don't need a new square bracket if a node directly goes to a head category but maybe that's the problem that I'm having. Your trees all have labels and it represents each level of hierarchy. The kind of tree in my context is one where only the semantic types are illustrated and the phrase strucure is "neglected".

Comment: @FeyzaNalbant Yes in `qtree` you don't need brackets around terminal nodes. As for the labels, whether they are syntactic or semantic doesn't really matter.

Comment: Nice side by side comparison, Alan! This answer should be bookmarked as a tutorial for the basics of drawing syntax trees in any tree package!